# How can I display word document content on visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce

I am uploading word document in Document folder and trying to get that document information and displaying on visualforce page. Not able to do.

Thanks in advance.

Venkat.

Comment: What have you tried so far? You said not able to do, means you tried some code and its not working. If that so, please post your code in your question so we can take a look and help you out.

Answer (score 2):

It is not directly possible. You will have to use a [Salesforce CRM Content](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=content_about.htm&language=en_US) to that:

> **Previewing**
>  In Salesforce CRM Content you do not need to download a
>   large document to determine if its content is relevant to you. The
>   content details page provides document details at a glance, including
>   document title, author, description, tags, libraries, comments, votes,
>   versions, subscribers, and downloads. If the document is a Microsoft
>   PowerPoint, Word, Excel, or Adobe® PDF file, you can preview the
>   entire file in your browser without downloading it. Some aspects of
>   files may not be displayed in previews. Copy-protected PDFs can't be
>   previewed.

There are some tricky solutions but generally it is not supported by Visualforce:

- [Document preview with Visualforce](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/4715/document-preview-with-visualforce)
- [Content Previewer in Visualforce](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000099NrIAI)